# What does Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_EXTENSIONS actually mean in Screeps (game)

Tags: javascript, screeps

`createCreep()` is returning -13 which is Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_EXTENSIONS.  What does that mean, how do I fix it?  This is the code I'm running:

```
Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([Game.WORK, Game.WORK, Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE], 'harvester0', {role: 'harvester'});
```

I've verified with `console.log()` that the block of code is actually being run but nothing is being spawned and when I go to the console and run it by hand it returns -13.  Do I need more spawns, do I need to 'install' stuff on my spawn, if so I don't see any functions to install stuff in the docs, do I possibly need more energy?

Comment: If you're going to downvote please provide ways to make the question more clear.  I can't fix stuff with nothing but a downvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is at the end of the first page of screeps documentation : http://www.screeps.com/docs/concepts.php
You tried to create a creep with 6 parts while a standard creep can only have 5 parts.
You just need extensions. I haven't tried them yet.

> A standard spawn can spawn creeps up to 5 parts in length. Spawning
>   more complex creeps requires a spawn extension in the room. Each body
>   part needs one extension. For example, spawning of a 12-part creep
>   requires 7 extensions. During the spawning of a creep each spawn
>   extension consumes energy the same was as the spawn does, but on a
>   fixed basis: 200 units of energy per 1 extension. The exact location
>   of extensions within a room does not matter, but they should be in the
>   same room with the spawn (one extension can be used by several
>   spawns).